# What's does kube-down need?

Tags: kubernetes

I am running Kubernetes on AWS with my friends. The procedure is below.

1. My friend run `kube-up.sh` on his laptop.
2. We share kubeConfig file and environment variables so I can also connect to kubernetes.

But the problem is I cannot run `kube-down.sh` on my own laptop.
So I would like to know what else do I need in order to run `kube-down.sh`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a [kubernetes release](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases). You should download the same version that was used to create the cluster, unpack it, change into the `kubernetes` directory, and then run kube-down.sh.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but we are using the same version of kubernetes. So I guess there is more I need.

Comment: You said that you could not run kube-down. What fails? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Actually it didn't return any error message. But all the kubernetes just remain the same on AWS.

Comment: say we have an existing cluster created via kube-up, and on a different machine how do you run kube-down to destroy that cluster? i did the same, using just the kubeConfig, but it says "done" but everything remains on the server. Im using AWS EC2

Comment: In addition to having the same kubeconfig file, you need to have the same parameters in [config-default.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/aws/config-default.sh) so that the script tries to tear down the correctly named resources.